# DisplayType Test Class

Tags: apex

Will someone advise on how to get code coverage for Schema.DisplayType displayType?
For example: Utilhelper is class name

```
 @TestVisible 
 private String getFieldTypes( Schema.DisplayType displayType ){
        String result = 'text';
        if( !stringTypes.contains( displayType )){
            if( urlTypes.contains( displayType )){
                return 'url';
            }
            else if( dateTypes.contains( displayType )){
                return 'date-local';
            }
            else if( numberTypes.contains( displayType )){
                return 'number';
            }
            else if( displayType == percentType ){
                return 'percent';
            }
            else if( displayType == moneyType ){
                return 'currency';
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: We don't know how to help you with just this snippet. Generically speaking, you'd pass in each displayType to this method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sfdcfox.  I just put the snippet figuring if I had 1 example I could figure out the remaining.  So do you mean something like this: 
Utilhelper.getFieldTypes('url')

Comment: You can do something like `Schema.DisplayType dt = Schema.DisplayType.TEXTAREA` and pass it to the method like `Utilhelper.getFieldTypes(dt)` and assert it.

Comment: Thanks for the help manjit5190 its not liking the Utilhelper.getFieldTypes(dt).  Basically saying that method does not exist even though I have the @TestVisible annotation.  Not sure why.

Comment: It's because the method is not static. @manjit5190 you hit it on the head; do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
Schema.DisplayType dt = Schema.DisplayType.TEXTAREA
String result = new Utilhelper().getFieldTypes(dt)
```

and assert it.